# +1 bows and arrows

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

In D&D 5e, I am wondering how mechanically using +1 bows and arrows (or crossbow and bolts) work, specifically:

1. If a character uses a +1 bow but mundane arrows, do they get +1 to both the attack roll and the damage roll?
2. If a character uses a +1 arrow but a mundane bow do they get +1 to both the attack roll and the damage toll?
3. If they use both a +1 bow and a +1 arrow do the effects stack so that the character gets +2 to attack and damage rolls?

The way I have been working it is that a +1 bow grants the bonus to attack rolls, and the +1 arrow grands the bonus to damage rolls. Is this correct?

Comment: Please let us know if that doesn't answer your question and specify what is missing. Happy to reopen if this doesn't solve it for you!

Comment: @London Please don't answer in comments. If you'd like, you can add that to an answer to the linked question.